# Correct wrongly-encoded Unicode string

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8

Some data in my database has been inserted with wrong encoding.

When I fetch the data and dump it, I get following output:

```
$VAR1 = "\x{fffd}U/mL"
```

How to correct it?
I tried `decode_utf8`, `decode_utf8` in Perl.

Comment: Do you know what this string should have been? It's looking like you're lost some unformation, as `U+FFFD` is *REPLACEMENT CHARACTER* whis is used in place of an invalid Unicode character

Comment: Yes: we need input and output character correspondingly

Comment: It might be too late; the information might be lost. 1) What kind of database is this? 2) What do you get from `use Data::Dumper; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($row));` when you fetch a this value from the database? Make sure that you're NOT using the `mysql_enable_utf8` option or similar when doing this debugging.

Answer (score 2):

The `decode_utf8` assumes that you have the right octets. If you start with the wrong data, it won't fix it. In general, this is something that you can't highly automate since that data can be messed up in so many ways.